# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $V$ satisfying $T^2 = T$. Find its eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, and suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Then for some $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$, $Tv = \lambda v$.

But then, this implies that: $T^2 v = T(Tv) = T(\lambda v) = \lambda Tv = \lambda^2 v$. However, since $T^2 = T$, this must hold for all vectors in $V$.

In particular, $Tv = T^2 v \implies \lambda v = \lambda^2 v \iff \lambda^2 = \lambda$. Hence, we must have that $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 0$.

Have I done something wrong??

Comment: Why do you think you've done something wrong? This is definitely true for real vector spaces, at least...

Comment: You might want to justify the existence of "an eigenvalue of $T$" first in order to make your argument work.

Comment: Well, what if you take $T \equiv I$? It satisfies $T^2 = T$ but $\lambda = 1$ with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: "Then for **some** $v\in V$ with $v\neq 0$, we have $Tv=\lambda v$. "

Comment: The assumptions I stated in the title of my question is all we are given.

Comment: Also "we must have that $\lambda=1$" **or** $\lambda=0$".

Comment: Okay Jack. Thank you. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that if you have an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then it is either $0$ or $1$. However, this is the most you can say; consider when $T$ is the identity transformation. Then $T^2=T$ but $0$ is not an eigenvalue. There are actually linear transformations that have *no* eigenvalues, so the first statement I mentioned is really all you can say.

Answer (score 0):

$0$ and $1$ need not both arise as eigenvalues (consider the cases when $T$ is the identity and when it is $0$), but $0$ and $1$ are indeed the only possible eigenvalues. Your calculation is fine, just be careful because it only shows that $0$ and $1$ are the only possible eigenvalues, not that both actually occur (and the calculation holds for all eigenvectors in $V $, not all vectors). You could also see the result by observing that the minimal polynomial of $T $ divides $X^2 -X $.

Answer (score 0):

hint :
use the fact that  the polynomial $X^2-X$ vanish $T$ and splits with simple roots , so T is diagonalisable , thus the eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of this polynomial 
conclusion : the eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $V= \ker(T) \oplus \ker(I-T)$ and $T(V)= \ker(I-T)$. Hence we have:

1. $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$  iff $T=0$
2. $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$  iff $T=I$
3. $0$ and $1$ are eigenvalues of $T$ iff $0 \ne T \ne I$